# $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,...,x_n]/(f(x_1,...,x_n))$ for$ f(x_1,...,x_n)$ irreducible are all homeomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Since $k[X]$ is PID, we know that any ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial $f$ is prime and thus maximal, so $A=k[X]/(f)$ is a field and thus $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is just a point. So we see that for any irreducible polynomial $f$, all the spectra $V(f)$ are homeomorphic topological spaces.

I wonder if this is true for $k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$, and more generally for $k[x_1,...,x_n]/(f(x_1,...,x_n))$.

> That is:
>
> **1)** Is it true that $\operatorname V((h(x_1,...,x_n)))\cong \operatorname V((f(x_1,...,x_n)))$ for any pair of irreducible polynomials?

(Where by $\cong$ I mean homeomorphism of topological spaces, because I think that if I ask for an isomorphism of affine schemes the claim is false already for $n=2$.)

> **2)** I think it is true for $n=2$, can you point me to a proof or counterexample?

**Edit.**
Following @ThorWittich comment, I'm interested also in answers that assume something about the cardinality or characteristic of the field.

**Notation.** By $\operatorname V((f))$ I mean the space of all primes containing the ideal generated by $f$, with the Zariski topology. In other words, I just mean $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,...,x_n]/(f)$.

Comment: Can you explain your notation? Does $V(h)$ stands for the variety defined by $h=0$? The equality in 1) means equality or homoeomorphism?

Comment: @Mohan I edited my notation. Yes, I mean homeomorphism of topological spaces, not equality. I also think that the homeomorphism of topological spaces should not necessarily lift to an isomorphism of affine schemes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $y$ and $y^2-x^3-x$ are irreducible in say $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but the corresponding specs are not homeomorphic. One of them is simply connected and the other not.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me why it is not simply connected?

Comment: @plant May be it is easier to consider $xy-1$. This too is irreducible and the zero set is easily seen to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$, which is not simply connected.

Comment: Thank you. This looks right... It is strange because I actually found the claim without proof about the case $n=2$ in a well known alg. geometry textbook